# Laravel custom form request get id

Tags: php, laravel

I have in controller controller methods: store, and update:

```
public function store(AddEditShopRequest $request)
{
    $extra = ['user_id' => Auth::user()->id, 'slug' => str_slug($request->title)];
    $shop = Shop::create(array_merge($request->all(), $extra));

    return redirect()->back();
}

public function update(AddEditShopRequest $request, Shop $shop)
{
    $shop->update($request->all());

    return redirect()->back();
}
```

And I have Request: AddEditShopRequest:

```
public function authorize()
{
    return true;
}

/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'title' => 'required|string|min:3|max:15|unique:shops,title,' . 
    $this->id,
    ]
}
```

When user update the shop, `$this->id` get me null, I tryied: `$this->route('shop')->id` and worked, but When user store shop, laravel get me error: `Trying to get property 'id' of non-object`.

How I can fix this?

Comment: Better create two different request class for add and edit. Your request class always expect shop object which is not available in your store route.

Comment: Yes because at that time there is no $this->id
you need to add conditions based rules

Comment: This could be a lot simpler. What's the relationship of `Shop` with `User`?